# How to prove this expression in Discrete-math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have such an expression that I need to prove. But I don't know the way to solve it. If you have please send me a link where I can read about it in order to understand how to solve this.

$$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap C)$$

Comment: Now that you have posted your question, look at the Related links on the bottom right: it will have questions (and answers) just like yours!

Comment: @Bram28 actually no... I see tab `Related`, but I don't see similar questions...

Comment: @MatthewDaly maybe you have a link where I can find how to write expressions in Math SO editor?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You bet.  Welcome!  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Show that any element of the set on the left must be in the set on the right and vice versa.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko That very first one shows several strategies for proving set equality statements like yours: you either show that every element is in the first set if and only if it is in the second, or you use set-theoretic equivalence principles to go from the one side of the equation to the other side. Sure, it is not the *exact* same equality, but the proof techniques remain exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
A\setminus(B\setminus C)
&= A\cap(B\cap C^c)^c\tag*{Set Complement Law}\\
&= A\cap(B^c\cup C)\tag*{De Morgan’s Law}\\
&= (A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap C)\tag*{Distributive Law}\\
&= (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap C)\tag*{Set Complement Law}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, I got it. It was not so hard, I just was not on the way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**$\ A\setminus(B\setminus C)=A\cap\overline{\left(B\cap\overline{C}\right)}\ $.

Apply [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to the expression in parentheses, and use the distributivity of intersection over union: $\ P\cap(Q\cup R)=$$(P\cap Q)\cup(P\cap R)\ $ for any sets $\ P, Q, R\ $.